# Is there SOQL editor with code completion / intellisense?

Tags: soql

Basically I am looking to reduce the pain of adhoc queries that I currently do via the Developer Console.

Is there such an animal?

Comment: The data loader offers field completion... I think that's probably the best you're going to see these days, but I'd love to be wrong.

Comment: @sfdcfox Data Loader?  You mean the tool to import/export data to/from SFDC?  Where is the field completion?  I think I must be missing something.

Comment: Workbench you can select fields you want to build your query or even in eclipse Schema you can select fields and built query .There is no autocomplete ability though .

Comment: I prefer Force.com explorer personally especially during testing when I can easily update and delete data.But auto completion for query is not available.

Comment: Developer console will let you build queries from the object. From Dev Console, go to file > open > objects > {your object}. Select fields. Select query. Not intellisense, but maybe gets at what you're after in a different way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer to Use CloudingoStudio, it' free and works very well.
You can read more here: http://www.symphonicsource.com/cloudingo-studio/

It implements also a syntax similar to SQL like "Select * FROM ..." and the export to EXCEL functionality.

Read the user guide to have a complete view of what you could accomplish with it ;)

Comment: Happy to help man ;)

Answer (score 3):

I have not seen any auto suggest feature for query building but closest i can think is workbench .

[image]

Answer (score 3):

@AngryHacker, I think you will like [this feature of HaoIDE](https://github.com/xjsender/SublimeApexScreenshot/blob/master/Completions.gif), check the `SOQL Fields Completion` part in the demo.

Updated at 2015-05-27, See this [new feature](https://github.com/xjsender/SublimeApexScreenshot/raw/master/BuildSOQL.gif)

Comment: This is off topic, but I'm curious how HaoIDE compares to MavensMate for Salesforce development.

Answer (score 3):

[**Illuminated Cloud**](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/) plugin for IntelliJ IDEA can perform a true SOQL query autocompletion

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Force.com IDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_getting_started.htm) the eclipse based IDE allows to build a query graphically.

The Schema Explorer is a tool for browsing the objects and fields in a Force.com organization. The browser presents the logged-in user’s view of the Force.com database model, including object visibility, permissions, data types, lookup values and other information that is useful in developing applications on the Force.com platform.

The Schema Explorer is depicted as a hierarchical tree view of your organization’s schema. It is read-only and does not interact with the rest of the workspace in any way.

The right hand side panel of the browser is the hierarchical tree view of all the objects in the database. You can use this to drill down to an object of interest, and select fields within that object. The query pane on the left will then automatically be filled with a SOQL query that returns those objects and fields. Or you can enter your own SOQL query right into the box. Hitting the Run Me button will execute the query and show the results in the table below.

[image: Force.com]

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained how to access and use this feature in the IDE.  Doesn't have to be complete, but at least enough to get started would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use soqlxplorer from [pocketsoap!!](http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/soqlx/).
Especially if you have a mac machine this is a great tool too. You can save records in a snap, you can edit field values directly from the results pane, delete and many more. Worth exploring.

Answer (score 1):

I use workbench for query formation and mavensmate pulgin for sublime for code editing. Workbench offers easy query formation. Mavensmate offers good code completion while coding. Have a look at ForceExplorer also in the link https://developer.salesforce.com/page/ForceExplorer

Answer (score 1):

I have [created open source project to automatically create SOQL](https://soqlbuilder.herokuapp.com/). You can either use it directly or modify code and deploy on heroku.

Below are few features :

- Toggle between API name and Label Name
- Search Objects or Fileds needs to build SOQL (In my case, it was
  primitive. I had more than 70 Objects and many of those objects has
  300+ fields)
- Checkboxes to select fields (No need to hold control button to select
  multiple fields) Automatic Query Builder at Right side of page
- Shows API count used by application
- Search returned records
- Sorting on Table Headers
- Pagination

You can find related [blog article here](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/creating-salesforce-query-builder-in-node-js-and-angularjs-using-salesforce-rest-api-and-oauth2/), [complete source code](https://github.com/JitendraZaa/SOQLBuilder) and [running application here](https://soqlbuilder.herokuapp.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You may use Schema Explorer in JetForcer plugin for exploring your Salesforce data. (I participate in developing this plugin)
It provides many more features than just code completion.

see docs here: https://jetforcer.com/pages/features/soql-query-editor

[image]

Comment: here is a good overview of all available features
https://blog.jetforcer.com/schema-explorer/

Answer (score 1):

I'm a part of a team that has been working on [Maven Tools for Salesforce](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/maven-tools-for-salesforc/kgookdjjmmekebgdecakmblghjgiaoem?hl=en), a Google Chrome extension that offers you a collection of Salesforce developer tools and it can help you with this issue.

Maven Tools has a Query Editor that has many great features, including autocompletion while typing queries, executing and exporting queries with large amounts of records, saving your most frequent queries and accessing your recent queries and much more.

Here's a little gif where you can see how the autocomplete feature works in Maven Tools:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use SOQL Studio from https://visualsoftwaresystems.net. It is by far the best tool I have seen for ad-hoc SOQL.  Line comments, block comments, full syntax highlighting, schema browser, detailed org, sobject, and field properties and more.  And I love that you are not limited to a single org or editor window and can save your SOQL for use at a later time.  It also has robust export capabilities.